# Converting strings longer than 8000 characters to Varbinary(MAX)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to convert some long strings to varbinary(max) as part of an INSERT. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/ms188362.aspx says that a varbinary(max) can hold up to 2^31-1 bytes. However, when I use:

```
CONVERT(varbinary(max),"ReallyLongString...")
```

the string gets truncated to 8000 characters.

Any ideas on how to get these strings into varbinary(max) without the truncation?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not put them in `varchar(max)` ?

Comment: It's an existing database and the field is a VARBINARY(MAX) field. without the conversion the message "Implicit conversion from data type varchar to varbinary(max) is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query." is displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the answer happened in the comments, I'll add it here and close off the Question. The long string in question was made up of a number of concatenated strings.

Martin Smith gave this answer:
*"Make sure the first string involved in the concatenation is cast to varchar(max). varchar(n) + varchar(n) will truncate at 8,000 characters not produce a varchar(max)"*

Which solved the problem. Thanks to both Martin and Joacim Isaksson for their help.

Answer (score 3):

This works on SQL Server 2012;

```
-- Insert
INSERT INTO myTable (value) VALUES 
    (CAST('<really long string>' AS VARBINARY(MAX)));

-- Retrieve
SELECT CAST(value AS VARCHAR(MAX)) FROM myTable;
```

Inserting a 10k character value will get the same value back, verified using `LEN` on the resulting VARCHAR(MAX).

```
-- Validate
SELECT LEN(CAST(value AS VARCHAR(MAX))) FROM myTable;

> 10000
```

[An SQLfiddle to play with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2f338/2). Sadly SQLfiddles setup can only take 8k characters, so had to build the 10k string in a variable.
Works as above with a normal quoted string constant in a local SQL manager.

Comment: This didn't work for me, I get 8000 as the output of the LEN() query

Comment: @LouisFellows With SQL Server 2012?

Comment: @LouisFellows - Is the string an actual string literal > 8000 characters or are you building it up through concatenation for example?

Comment: @LouisFellows I cannot repeat your problem, tested a 100k long normal quoted string, casting back and forth, saving and loading from a VARBINARY(MAX) column without any problems or data loss.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson - If I copy your SQLFiddle example in, it works just as you say. But not foe the string I'm using. Which means It's more than likely something to do with the string. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @MartinSmith It's built up from a number of smaller strings which may be the issue

Comment: @LouisFellows - Make sure the first string involved in the concatenation is cast to `varchar(max)`. `varchar(n)` +  `varchar(n)` will truncate at 8,000 characters not produce a `varchar(max)`

Comment: Yes, a quoted string longer than 8k characters is typed VARCHAR(MAX), a shorter one not. Concatenating two non VARCHAR(MAX) strings will indeed limit to 8k characters. Good call, @MartinSmith.

Comment: @MartinSmith That fixed it! Many Thanks! Could you add an answer so I can accept it?